# Реализация операции переворачивания всех строк в стеке за О(1)

Tags: c++, алгоритм, шаблоны-с++, vector, стек

Есть задание реализовать Stack , имеющий
в дополнение к обычным стековым операциям
операцию вычисления максимального элемента,
работающую за О(1) и Stack должен дополнительно иметь
операцию переворачивания всех строк,
находящихся в стеке, работающую за
О(1). В принципе, нахождение максимального элемента я реализовал, вроде бы как, прошу о помощи с перереворотами стрингов. Я просто не имею понятия как это сделать за О(1). Спасибо огромное заранее. Код:

//Stack.h

```
#ifndef STACK_H
#define STACK_H

#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <algorithm>

using namespace std;

template <typename T>
class Stack {
private:
    vector<T> maxelement;
    vector<T> elems;
public:
    T push(T const&);
    T pushfirst(T const&);
    T& pop() const;
    T top();
    T maxElement();
    bool empty(){
        return elems.empty();
    }
};

template <typename T>
T Stack<T>::pushfirst(T const& elem){
    maxelement.push_back(elem);
}

template <typename T>
T Stack<T>::push (T const& elem){
    elems.push_back(elem);
    if (maxelement.back() < elems.back()){
            maxelement.push_back(elems.back());
    }
}

template <typename T>
T& Stack<T>::pop ()const{
    if (elems.empty()){
        throw out_of_range( "Stack<>::pop(): empty stack" );
    }
    return elems.pop_back();
}

template <typename T>
T Stack<T>::top () {
    if (elems.empty()){
        throw out_of_range( "Stack<>::top(): empty stack" );
    }
    return elems.back();
}

template <typename T>
T Stack<T>::maxElement() {
    return maxelement.back();
}

//////////////


template <>
class Stack<string> {
private:
    vector<string> elements;
    vector<string> addelems;
public:
     void pushstring(string const&);
     string& popstring();
     string topstring();
     string topreversedstring();
     void reverseString();
};

void Stack<string>::pushstring(string const& elem){
    elements.push_back(elem);
}

string& Stack<string>::popstring(){
    if (elements.empty()){
        throw out_of_range( "Stack<>::pop(): empty stack" );
    }
    elements.pop_back();
    addelems.pop_back();
}

string Stack<string>::topstring () {
    if (addelems.empty()){
        throw out_of_range( "Stack<>::top(): empty stack" );
    }
    return addelems.back();
}

string Stack<string>::topreversedstring () {
    if (elements.empty()){
        throw out_of_range( "Stack<>::top(): empty stack" );
    }
    return elements.back();
}

void Stack<string>::reverseString(){
    for (int i = 0; i < elements.size(); i++){
        addelems.push_back(elements[i]);
        reverse(elements[i].begin(), elements[i].end());
    }
}

#endif // STACK_H
```

//main.cpp

```
#include <iostream>
#include "Stack.h"

int main()
{
    try{
        Stack<int> intStack;
        Stack<string> stringStack;

        intStack.pushfirst(7);
        intStack.push(7);
        cout << intStack.top() <<endl;
        intStack.push(2);
        cout << intStack.top() <<endl;
        intStack.push(4);
        cout << intStack.top() <<endl;
        intStack.push(99);
        cout << intStack.top() <<endl;

        cout << "Max Element is : " << intStack.maxElement() << std::endl;

        stringStack.pushstring("hello");
        stringStack.pushstring("world");


        stringStack.reverseString();

        cout << "Old string:  " << stringStack.topstring() << ", " << "Reversed string:  " << stringStack.topreversedstring() << std::endl;
        stringStack.popstring();
        cout << "Old string:  " << stringStack.topstring() << ", " << "Reversed string: " << stringStack.topreversedstring() << std::endl;
        stringStack.popstring();
        cout << "Old string:  " << stringStack.topstring() << ", " << "Reversed string: " << stringStack.topreversedstring() << std::endl;

        return 0;

    }
    catch ( exception const& ex ){
        cerr << "Exception: " << ex.what() << endl;
        return -1;
    }

}
```

И еще вопрос, не является ли костылем в программе, если я написал специальный метод для добавления первого элемента в 2 вектора, чтобы потом от этого плясать. Может быть, стоит это как-то по-другому, более умно сделать? Спасибо еще раз.

Comment: "Переворачивания всех строк" - это что? Реверс самих строк ("abcd" -> "dcba") или просто разворот самого стека (кто был первым - становится последним)?

Comment: @Harry, реверс самих строк на стеке.

Comment: Что-то я тогда не понимаю, как можно развернуть N строк за константное время - даже если строку можно было бы развернуть за O(1)... Хранить рядом строку в развернутом виде тоже не выход - это просто перенести работу во вставку.

Comment: За O(1) ? Разве это возможно?

Comment: @hOUSTANSTARxyolo Возможно Вы неправильно поняли задание. За O(1) нереально.

Comment: @Harry, а если я сразу буду засовывать в 2 вектора, в пуше, 2 строки - обычную и перевернутую, не пойдет? Может быть, можно как-то булевским полем проверять, перевернутая строка или нет? Я уже все варианты передумал, ничего похожего на работу за констатное время нет.

Comment: @JaponDemon я понял задание верно, в том то и дело.

Comment: Ничего не сказано про время вставки элементов. Т.е. можно сразу иметь два стека: прямых и перевернутых строк. Вставка потребует O(k) - где к - длинна строки, но это укладывается в задание. Вместо переворота строк по запросу, делать swap векторов, который O(1).

Comment: Скажем так - если не привязываться к O(1), просто вообще - вот надо мне получать строки из стека то такие, то эдакие - я бы просто хранил в стеке переменную, что возвращать, и `top` у меня возвращал бы строку либо прямую, либо обратную в зависимости от поля. Тогда вся "операция переворота" была бы O(1) - просто запись поля. Но тогда `top` превращалась бы в операцию O(длина строки). Если это время переворачивания строки не учитывать - то вот вам O(1) :) Но это как-то нечестно :) Второй вариант - как я уже сказал, хранить 2 строки - тут работа переносится во вставку, но это дороже, потому

Comment: что требует переворачивать **все** строки, в то время как вряд ли **все** строки будут нужны перевернутыми. Т.е. просто делаем лишнюю работу.

Comment: @Harry, если я правильно понял задачу, то в такой постановке одним флажок не обойтись: рассмотри ситуацию: «переворот→вставка→переворот». Соответственно должен быть флажок у каждой строки, а это уже O(N), так что если условие действительно такое, то ничего проще двух стеков на ум не приходит...

Comment: Вероятно имелось в виду,  для структуры реализовать возможность оборота всего содержимого за одну операцию, вроде stringStack.reverseAll(); и не более того. Ох уж эти студенческие задания...

Comment: @JaponDemon, это и имелось ввиду :)

Comment: @Fat-Zer возможно. 2 стек просто не строковый а флаговый. При извлечении применять флаг в обратную сторону.

Comment: @pavel, да, тоже вариант... но у меня всё же стойкое впечатление, что в задаче подразумевается «перевернуть стек», а не инвертировать каждую строку...

Comment: если под "переворачиванием  всех строк" понимать возможность с другого конца удалять/добавлять в стек, то deque можно использовать. К примеру, `Stack s; s.push('a'); s.push('b'); s.pop() /* -> b */; s.push('c'); s.reverse(); s.pop() /* -> a */; s.pop() /* -> c */`